# Which subtitle formats does mencoder support?

Tags: video, avi, subtitles, video-conversion, mencoder

I've been able to use mencoder with .srt files, but are there any other formats that mencoder supports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `mplayer(1)` man page:

> ... are supported along with 12 subtitle formats (MicroDVD, SubRip, OGM, SubViewer, Sami, VPlayer, RT, SSA, AQTitle, JACOsub, PJS  and our  own: MPsub) and DVD subtitles (SPU streams, VOBsub and Closed Captions).